# Android Studio text dissapear after i make button smaller android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make my button smaller, but when i do it text dissapear. Also i can't change size of other buttons. For example CLEAR button. I can't make it smaller. It seems like it adapts to size/lenght of a text or just padding of a button is too big, but androd:padding sucks

[Before changing a size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRjpc.png)
[After:] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf0Zj.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="388dp"
        android:layout_height="549dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.681"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"

                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"

                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"

                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"

                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"

                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"

                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="CLEAR" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plus"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/minus"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/equal"
                android:layout_width="43dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="=" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tableLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

please help.i have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed width of the TableLayout to match_parent, so that we do not need to set the fix size, which can be very tricky.

```
 <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="549dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.681"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
```

Now, for each child of the TableRow, instead of layout_weight set the layout_column to 1, so that each of its children occupies same space.

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"

            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"

            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </TableRow>
```

I also changed px to dp for the height. I hope that now you can change your button size and that the text will be visible.